# React virtualized Infinite Scroll rendering aggregated data

Tags: reactjs, aggregate, react-virtualized

I have an Infinite Loader List component which renders array of data. I needed to aggregate my data (grouped by days), so I made two levels array:

```js
list = {
  [ 
    {
      group:'09-20',
      data: [
        content: 'content',
        contentInfo: 'contentInfo'
      ]
    },

    {
      group:'09-21',
      data: [
        content: 'content',
        contentInfo: 'contentInfo'
      ]
    },
  ]
    // and so on...
}
```

Is there a way to render this? I tried to map the second array (called data here) in `renderRow` function, but the result is buggy scrolling (data flickers because of rendering, and `loadMoreRows` func is not triggered)

`renderRow`:

```js
  renderRow = ({ index, key, style }) => {
    let content;
    if (!this.state.results[index]) content = <ActivityLogRowLoading />;
    else {
      const data = this.state.results[index].data.map(element => (
        <Element>
          <Content>{element.description}</Content>
          <Date>
            {moment(element.created).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss')}
          </Date>
        </Element>
      ));
      content = (
        <div>
          {this.state.results[index].group} 
          {data}
        </div>
      );
    }
    return (
      <div key={key} style={style}>
        {content}
      </div>
    );
  };
```

Comment: `renderRow` code ?

Comment: Hi @xadm, I updated my post with `renderRow` function.

Comment: No problems w/o mapping? Mapped `<Element/>` (its top div) needs keys, too.  Convert renderRow, pass row data to full (pure) component - give it responsibility to show/hide inner entries - accordion style? create [mcve] at stackblitz?

Comment: @xadm Sorry for late answer, I will try to create minimal working example. I discovered, that the problem is with row height - which should be generated dynamically. So I followed documentation and created some functions to return height of single row based on its size. The problem still appeared.